# problem accessing to a web api using ms adal from an angular app

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to access to an asp.net web api from an angular app using adal-angular4.
According to the documentation I created the two app, exposed the api, granted admin consent, authorized the client application.
I'm able to login correctly using my outlook.com account, but when I try to call the web api, I receive this error message:

zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '4c929341-ed77-441d-8759-*****' named '***-client'

Looks like this happen before the actual call to the web api itself, between the call invocation of the get calll of the angular http service and the real http call to the server.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you clicked Grant admin consent button for your Web API side in AAD?

Comment: yes, I clicked the Grant Admin and added to the client list

Comment: Hi Luca, did you ever solve this I think I have a similar issue?